# Spring MVC giving 404 for root

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have a springmvc application which I am mostly using to serve up JSON data. All of the pages will be decided via Angular.  I have a index.jsp that I need to be able to view which is at the root of the WEB-INF directory.

Because I am sending everything through dispatcher the request for root is being picked up and sent through. Since there is no controller that maps to root it is being rejected and throwing a 404.

My question is how do I allow the pass through of the index.jsp without disrupting the rest of the application?

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cr</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/spring-controllers.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cr</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the `index.jsp` file inside the root of your webcontext.  Then use the following filter mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cr</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The `/` mapping will pick up all requests which cannot be resolved.  It essentially acts as a catch all when no other mappings can be found.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
web.xml config:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:springMVC.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

springMVC.xml config:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="/pages/index"/>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

If correct,path `/` will get the view file `/WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp`,but I get a 404 error. 
Finally,I found the reason.Because have a `index.html` file in the ROOT folder.When I remove the file,it works correct.

Comment: You should clean this up more so it looks less like "I have this problem too" and more like "here is how to solve the problem and why"